# Let $X$ and $Y$ have the joint pdf $f(x,y)=8x(1-y),0<y<1,0<x<1-y$. Compute $P(Y<X\mid X \leqq \frac{1}{4})$

Tags: probability, self-learning

> Let $X$ and $Y$ have the joint pdf $f(x,y)=8x(1-y)$, $0<y<1$, $0<x<1-y$. Compute $P(Y<X\mid X \leqq \frac{1}{4})$.

I know:

$$P(A\mid B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$$

Therefore I first compute $P(B \leqq \frac{1}{4})=\int_0^{\frac{1}{4}}4x$ to satisfy the denominator. To calculate the numerator I need to find the intersection of $A$ and $B$:

$$\int_0^{\frac{1}{4}} \int_0^x 8x(1-y)\:\mathrm{d}y\:\mathrm{d}x$$

Am I on the right track? My answer is extremely close, but not exactly correct.

Comment: You lost me at  $P(B \leqq \frac{1}{4})=\int_0^{\frac{1}{4}}4x$. Please explain.

Comment: Maybe if you _sketched_ the region on which the density is nonzero, you might find the work of deciding on what the limits ought to be a lot easier.

Comment: @DilipSarwate you are right, I will do this.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I sketched it out and found that y should run from 0 to x and that x should run from 0 to 1/4. This result I think should be divided by $P(B)$ to compute the conditional probability. The result, however, is not correct.

Comment: You've got areas $X,Y$ mixed up with $A,B$.

Comment: @Did This is the marginal pdf of $X$ from $0$ to $\frac{1}{4}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right integral for $P(A\cap B)$ but the wrong expression for $P(B)$,
which should be
$$
P(B) = \int_{x=0}^{1/4} dx \int_{y=0}^{1-x} 8x(1-y) dy$$ 
The upper limit in the $y$ integral comes from the fact that 
$$
x < 1-y \Leftrightarrow y < 1-x$$